# Change sort order based on facet selection

Tags: 7, search

My view displays Webinars, I use facets to choose between upcoming and archived.

The default sort order is ASC, which is fine for upcoming dates, but if you select the archived facet, I need the sort order to change to DESC. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i solved the problem in the end, i checked the current path using `request_path()` and if it matched my facet url, then use the `search_api_query_alter` hook to reverse the sort order:

```
function MYMODULE_search_api_query_alter(SearchApiQueryInterface $query) {
    $query->sort('my_field_name', 'DESC');
}
```